# Automatically set up user's subscription in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, ssis, sql-server, subscription

I have a very simple report in SSRS that is just a table with three columns, an object name, client account, and expiration date.

In my report, I include a filter by UserID to limit the data to just the logged in user's client accounts.

I store the user's client accounts in a simple table with `domain\alias | client account` fields which is populated from a SSIS package.

When an new `alias | client account` association is entered, I would also like to set up a subscription to the report for this `alias` so they are notified when it is updated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to use data driven reports because I am using userID as a parameter to my reports so what I ended up doing is add a `subscribe` bit field to my client access table that maps user aliases to client accounts. Then in my package that populates new users/clients, I send out an email to ONLY users associated with accounts that meet a specific criteria.

User's are not able to manage their own subscriptions (which would be nice), but this will be an interim solution that should work great until we investigate our larger needs which will fit in with a billing system.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx